# How to parse a json object using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I think that it is a very basic question, but I have spent hours looking for an answer with no luck, I've the following json object (generated using play!Framework)

```
{
    "preg.pregunta": [{
        "message":"Debes escribir una pregunta",
        "key":"preg.pregunta",
        "variables":[]
    }],
    "preg":[{
        "message": "validation.object",
        "key":"preg",
        "variables":[]
    }]
}
```

This is my jquery piece of code

```
$.ajax({
    type: $target.attr('method'),
    data: dataString,
    url:$target.attr('action'),
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function() {
        //some stuff
    },
    success:function(response){
        //some stuff
    },
    error: function(response){
        //I want to use the json response here.
    }
});
```

I want to get all inside `preg.pregunta` (`message` and `key` values)

Any help?

**UPDATED**: well I don't have enough reputation to answer to myself, this is what I've found so far.

Ok maybe it would be more than obvious or I have to study a bit more; I found that jQuery doesn't parse properly a JSON response if it came along with a HTTP error (400 in this case).

someone knows why this behavior?

I just tested this code in `success` handler and works perfectly!

```
$.ajax({
  type: $target.attr('method'),
  data: dataString,
  url:$target.attr('action'),
  dataType: "json",
  beforeSend: function() {
  },
  success:function(response){
    //It is working perfectly!
    $.each(response,function(object){ //first loop of the object
      $.each(response[object],function(values){ //looping inside arrays
        console.log(response[object][values].key) //getting value "key"
        console.log(response[object][values].message) //getting value "message"
      });
    })
  },
  error: function(response){
    //nothing happens here
  }
});
```

UPDATED 2.

after searching about 2 hours, I've found a straightforward solution:

```
error: function(response){
//Note the jQuery.parseJSON function
var response = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
  $.each(response,function(object){
    $.each(response[object],function(values){
      console.log(response[object][values].key)
      console.log(response[object][values].message)
    });
  })
}
```

Explanation: when using error handler, jQuery returns a complex object describing the error, responseText contains the data retrieved from the server, so, you have to parse it using parseJSON function.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
error: function(response) {
    var pregunta = response["preg.pregunta"][0].message;
    var key = response["preg.pregunta"][0].key;
},
```

If there were multiple values within the `preg.pregunta` array, you would need to loop and replace the `[0]` with your iterating variable.

Also, I don't quite understand why you'd only want to access the reponse in the `error` handler only?

Finally, the code for accessing the JSON is native javascript. This is because when you receive the response it has been converted into a POJS object, no jQuery required.

Comment: Hi! I've tried it before with not success, "response['preg.pregunta'] is undefined"

Comment: What do you see in the console when you try the following: `console.log(response);`?

Comment: Hi Rory, well my answer is quite simple; I'm validating a field using playframework validators, If any error is found (a field empty for example) play returns a validation.errorsMap() object which is rendered as JSON so I can use it later, this response returns with a `HTTP 400` ... so thats why I catch it with the `error` handler.